I want to dynamically compute position of text using Imagemagick -annotate {X,Y} with -gravity , but I need an explanation of the X value
I can force text into the proper position using actual numeric values for X and Y in -annotate +X+Y, but I want to be able to compute the X and Y values (in my program) relative to the image size. I am using -gravity Northeast and NorthWest for both vertical and horizontal images of varying sizes. I want to be able to have the text inset a computed number of pixels from the edges of the image RELATIVE to the image size. In my testing, it seems that when using SouthEast, the X value I insert manually is relative to the right-hand edge of the image, which is counter-intuitive. Am I right?
I originally tried to set a margin from the left edge of the image, but that got strange results. So I tried using -gravity SouthEast -annotate +5+Y and got a right-hand margin of 5 pixels. When I changed to -annotate +7+Y I got a right-hand margin of 7 pixels. So I guess I don't really understand the X values when using -gravity.
This is the full parameter string I am passing to mogrify:
mogrify in.jpg -format jpg -font "Rockwell" -weight ExtraBold -fill gold -pointsize 63 ^ -stroke black 13 -strokewidth 14 -gravity SouthEast -annotate +5+100 “text1” ^ -stroke none -gravity SouthEast -annotate +5+100 ”text1” E:\\folders\\parent\\child1\\in.jpg


The origin is relative to the -gravity position.

Maybe you can see better if I draw some text with 2 different gravity settings and show the anchor point in red:
magick -size 640x480 xc:yellow \
  -font Roboto-Regular.ttf -pointsize 36 \
  -gravity northwest -annotate +40+10 "NW +40+10" \
  -gravity southeast -annotate +80+10 "SE +80+10" \
  -fill red \
  -draw "circle 40,10 40,15" \
  -draw "circle 560,470 560,475" result.png


